# Infinite loop with recursive template

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, recursion

I need to create a template which formats the table cells containing the golfer's score for each hole on the course with...

- Two parameters named parScore and holeScore. The parScore parameter contains
  the par for a selected hole on the course. The holeScore parameter contains the
  score the golfer achieved on the hole.
- A choose element that tests whether the holeScore parameter is equal to,
  less than, or greater than the parScore parameter. If holeScore is less than
  parScore, write the following code:
  holeScore
  where holeScore is the value of the holeScore parameter. If holeScore is greater
  than parScore, write the code:
  holeScore
  otherwise, write the code:
  holeScore

The following is the code that I have written but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop and I'm not sure if I'm calling the template properly or what the issue is?

```
<xsl:template name="formatHole">
    <xsl:param name="parScore" />
    <xsl:param name="holeScore" select="0" />

    <!-- Check to see if cells parameter is greater than 0-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$holeScore &lt; $parScore">
            <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$holeScore > $parScore">
            <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
        <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="$holeScore - 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="$parScore" />
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
```

The following is a snippet of the xml code...

```
<course>
   <par holeNumber="1">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="2">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="3">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="4">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="5">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="6">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="7">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="8">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="9">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="10">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="11">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="12">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="13">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="14">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="15">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="16">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="17">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="18">4</par>
</course>

<golfer>
   <name>Brett Bierson</name>
   <round roundNumber="1">
      <score holeNumber="1">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="3">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="4">2</score>
      <score holeNumber="5">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="6">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="8">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="9">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="10">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="11">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="12">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="13">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="14">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="15">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="16">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="17">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="18">3</score>
   </round>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do this using `call-templates`. All the information you need is on each node. What you have is [a pull (rather than a push) XSLT template](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xdpshpul.html). For each `score`, all you need to know is that you need to check it against the `par` for that given hole number, so only check that.

In the below template, we only look at the score in isolation, apart from searching in the course for the corresponding data for that hole. This means how we treat a score is isoalted from every other score.

```
<xsl:template match="score">
    <xsl:variable name="holeScore" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="holeNum" select="@holeNumber" />    
    <xsl:variable name="parScore" select="/data/course/par[@holeNumber = $holeNum]" />
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@holeNumber"/></td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$holeScore &amp;lt; $parScore">
            <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$holeScore &amp;gt; $parScore">
            <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

We can call this easily when rendering the table, by just using `apply-templates` for each score that a golfer has in their course:

```
    <xsl:template match="golfer">
      <h2>Scores for <xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Hole</td><td>Score</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./round/score"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

---

### In complete form, this transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          .low {
            background-color:red;
          }
          .high {
            background-color:green;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/golfer"/>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="golfer">
      <h2>Scores for <xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Hole</td><td>Score</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./round/score"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="score">
        <xsl:variable name="holeScore" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="holeNum" select="@holeNumber" />    
        <xsl:variable name="parScore" select="/data/course/par[@holeNumber = $holeNum]" />
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@holeNumber"/></td>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$holeScore &amp;lt; $parScore">
                <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
            </xsl:when>
    
            <xsl:when test="$holeScore &amp;gt; $parScore">
                <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
            </xsl:when>
    
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="$holeScore" /></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Applied to this document (I had to wrap it in an extra tag to make it valid XML):

```
<data>
<course>
   <par holeNumber="1">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="2">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="3">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="4">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="5">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="6">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="7">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="8">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="9">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="10">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="11">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="12">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="13">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="14">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="15">5</par>
   <par holeNumber="16">4</par>
   <par holeNumber="17">3</par>
   <par holeNumber="18">4</par>
</course>

<golfer>
   <name>Brett Bierson</name>
   <round roundNumber="1">
      <score holeNumber="1">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="2">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="3">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="4">2</score>
      <score holeNumber="5">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="6">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="7">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="8">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="9">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="10">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="11">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="12">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="13">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="14">4</score>
      <score holeNumber="15">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="16">5</score>
      <score holeNumber="17">3</score>
      <score holeNumber="18">3</score>
   </round>
</golfer>
</data>
```

### Gives this file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                  .low {
                    background-color:red;
                  }
                  .high {
                    background-color:green;
                  }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Scores for Brett Bierson</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hole</td>
                    <td>Score</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td class="low">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td class="high">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td class="low">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>16</td>
                    <td class="high">5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td class="low">3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

### Which looks like this:

[image: Example table from the given data]

Answer (score 0):

At then end, your template calls your template:

```
<xsl:template name="formatHole">
    [...]
    <xsl:call-template name="formatHole">
        <xsl:with-param name="parScore" select="$holeScore - 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" select="$parScore" />
    </xsl:call-template>   
</xsl:template>
```

This would explain why it does not end. In the same way that in JavaScript:

```
function foo() {
    foo();
}
```

won't end. Or more likely the JavaScript version would end with a stack overflow. The XSLT code does not end because I think the XSLT interpreter performs [tail call optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailCallOptimization). (It becomes an iteration.)

Answer (score -2):

I know nothing about golf, so I am only guessing here. It looks like you want to create a cell for each score in a round, and compare it with the par of the corresponding holeNumber of the course.

There are a few problems with your template: first, you never check for the iterator running under 0 (although you do have a comment saying you should). Next, your choice of holeScore as the iterator makes no sense: you need to iterate from 1 up to 18, not from 4 or 5 down to 0. Also, you keep comparing to the same par at every iteration.

Now, assuming this is done in the context of a round, you could do it in a much simpler way. First, place the following at the beginning of your stylesheet, outside of any template:

```
<xsl:key name="par" match="par" use="@holeNumber" />
```

Next, when in the context of a round, do something like:

```
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@roundNumber" /></td>
    <xsl:call-template name="createCells"/>
</tr>
```

Finally, this is the called template:

```
<xsl:template name="createCells">
    <xsl:for-each select="score">
        <xsl:variable name="par" select="key('par', @holeNumber)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; $par">
            <td class="low"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test=". > $par">
            <td class="high"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes that each round has exactly 18 scores. If this is not a valid assumption, you *will* need to use a recursive template with an iterator.